# 'int' object is not iterable in python

Tags: python, object, int, iterable

I keep getting the error 'int' object is not iterable, but I can't figure out why, any suggestions?

```
def printMatching(seq1, seq2):
is_match = []
if len(seq1) < len(seq2):
    short_seq = seq1
else:
    short_seq = seq2
for i in len(short_seq):
    if seq1(i) == seq2(i):
        is_match.append(true)
    else:
        is_match.append(false)

def main():
    seq1 = "abaababb"
    seq2 = "aabbaababa"
    printMatching(seq1, seq2)
```

Comment: `for i in len(short_seq)` is wrong. One can't *iterate* a number. It is just a number. Use `for i in range(num)` to iterate `[0..n)` or just iterate the sequence directly. In this case I suspect that using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and/or comprehensions would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(len(short_seq))
```

You're currently looping over a single number, which is not allowed. range(int) creates a list of values from [0,input).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in len(short_seq):
```

This line has errors. You need to have something like

```
for i in range(len(short_seq)):
```

i in - This basically checks for i in a iterable. Since len(short_seq) is not a iterable, it throws an error.